# Custom nameservers over wifi hotspots with initial web login

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, dns, nat, hotspot

I have built a portable router using a raspberry pi. My setup works, unless I connect to a hotspot that requires some kind of web based login.

After some investigation, I think I've tracked it down to a **nameserver** issue. I am using google's nameservers in my dhcpd.conf file below, this works without issues when i connect to hotspots that dont require an initial web login (home wifi, for example).

> /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf

```
ddns-update-style none;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
authoritative;
log-facility local7;

subnet 192.168.111.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.168.111.100 192.168.111.200;
  option broadcast-address 192.168.111.255;
  option routers 192.168.111.1;
  default-lease-time 600;
  max-lease-time 7200;
  option domain-name "local-network";
  option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
}
```

Removing the `option domain-name-servers` line makes all clients on `wlan1` unable to resolve hostnames.

I am able to find the current hotspot's nameservers inside `/etc/resolv.conf`

> /etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 212.27.40.241
nameserver 212.27.40.240
```

On my macbook, if I [manually enter](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH11162?locale=en_US) these nameservers in the network settings area, I am redirected to the hotspot's login page.
Once logged in, I can remove these manual entries and it will revert to the name servers provided by my DHCP server.

However, this is not an optimal solution as the connected hotspot on `wlan0` will change as I travel and I will have more than one device connected to `wlan1`.

My goal here is to remove this last step. Is there some way to automate this **on the raspberrypi server**? Or am I approaching this in the wrong way? Is the best solution to always use the hotspot's default DNS? If so, how do i instruct `dhcpd` to do so automatically?

Some info about my setup:

- 2 physical wifi adapters
- `wlan0` to connect to various hotspots
- `wlan1` to create a local network.
- `isc-dhcp-server` (`dhcpd`) to distribute IP addresses over `wlan1`
- `hostapd` to create a local hotspot
- NAT traversal using `iptables`

Answer (score 0):

In order for this to work, you need to **actually log in** to the hotspot using a web interface. There are some scripts that can do this automatically with varying level of success, you may try your luck with e.g. Zeroshell or similar.